# how to check app running in foreground or background in ionic/cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Is there any way to check whether the app is running in foreground or background in ionic/cordova/phonegap, I need to use it on android and ios, thanks a lot

Comment: ... read the documentation. A pause eventlistener will tell you when the user closes the app. The resume eventlistener will do the opposite of that.

Comment: thanks Sithys, in that case, I need to store a variable(let's say A) in the local storage, whose value will be changed by resume/pause eventlistener, then according to the A's value to determine the app's foreground/background, right? but It's feels not directly, is there any more directly method? Thanks in advance

Comment: The Resume and Pause events will be fired independently from a variable or sth like this. They will be fired if the user presses the home button, or if the user resumes the application.

Comment: @Sithys - simply listening for fired events doesn't answer the question that @user1521398 asked "Is there any way to check whether the app is running in foreground or background"... @user1521398 - yes you would need to use the `pause` and `resume` events with a variable to store the state (see the answered provided by @jurer).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the two Events "`Pause`" and "`Resume`". You will find all Events here in the [Apache Cordova Events Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html).

Event - Pause:

- *The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application into the background, typically when the user switches to a different application.*

Event - Resume

- *The resume event fires when the native platform pulls the application
  out from the background.*

You can add an Eventlistener for that into your code. For those two Events that would be:

**Pause - Quick Example**

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event
}
```

Or **Full Example** like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pause Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    }

    // Handle the pause event
    //
    function onPause() {
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Resume - Quick Example**

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
    // Handle the resume event
}
```

Or **Full Example** like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Resume Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    }

    // Handle the resume event
    //
    function onResume() {
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Try that out and let me know, if you need further help!

Comment: Thanks the details example, Sithys

Comment: hi, the pause/resume events do not fire immediately once the device is ready. My app was supposed to detect this event on another page in the app and during that time, my app could be at the background. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I need to know if the app has been launched in background (like after a VoIP push). Do you know how we could do that?

Answer (score 51):

For Ionic 2 and Ionic 3 the solution is:

```js
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  template: `OK`
})

constructor(public platform: Platform) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {

      if (platform.is('cordova')){

        //Subscribe on pause i.e. background
        this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
          //Hello pause
        });

        //Subscribe on resume i.e. foreground 
        this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
          window['paused'] = 0;
        });
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: why you are setting window['paused'] = 0; ? after checking the app is in foreground?

Comment: Yes when app came to foreground mode I set it for my case. You don't need it.

Comment: okay, cool, actually in iOS when app is in foreground state I am not getting firebase push notification. so I am thinking about creating own local notification, by checking platform and foreground condition... and pass the data into it.

Comment: What kid of plugin do you use for notifications?

Comment: phonegap plugin push

Comment: The reason may be in version on plugin. You need latest, and in payload data that you sending from server.

Comment: have you every used firebase push notification in iOS? and you are getting a push notification when the app is in the foreground?

Comment: Yes, I do. You need to subcribe on push events

Comment: @AlexanderZakusilo: sir above exaple working correctly if i call watchPostion function inside pause event function is not fire,can u tell me sir why function not fire?

Comment: @Kapilsoni No. I can't for now. I didn't try your case.

Comment: @Kapilsoni I think you need create issue at github for this case at ionic account.

Comment: @Alexander:- thanks for u reply sir but sir github is not give me reply of any issue

Answer (score 13):

A small service for Ionic based on Sithys answer:

```
factory('BackgroundCheck', function($ionicPlatform){
    var service = {};
    var inBackground = false;

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {        
        document.addEventListener("resume", function(){inBackground = false;}, false);
        document.addEventListener("pause", function(){inBackground = true;}, false);
    });

    service.isActive = function(){
        return inBackground == false;
    }
    return service;    
})
```

Answer (score 8):

#### *"Is there any way to check whether the app is running in foreground or background?"*

Yes.

1) When an app becomes inactive (runs in the background) Cordova fires the `pause` event, and when an app becomes active again (brought to the foreground) Cordova fires the `resume` event.

2) From these events, one can use a variable to store the state as "foreground" or "background".

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", function readyCallback() {


    var isAppInForeground = true;


    document.addEventListener("pause", function pauseCallback() {
      isAppInForeground = false;
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("resume", function resumeCallback() {
      isAppInForeground = true;
    }, false);

});
```

Comment: can i add the $Interval method inside the Pause event, which executes Location fetching task every 5 minutes.. will it work ?

Comment: This is actually the correct answer to the question

Comment: @tfmontague: sir can we call watchPosition function is call inside pause event?

Comment: @ManushVenkatesh - This listens for the "pause" event, and executes some code before the app is paused. Once the app is paused I don't believe it will continue to execute any code. You would need to run your code in a background thread, something like "https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode".

Comment: @KapilSoni - No, this listens for the "pause" event, and executes some code before the app is paused. Once the app is paused I don't believe it will continue to execute any code. You would need to run your code in a background thread, something like "https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode".

Comment: @tfmontague: thanks for ur response sir but i have already used bakground mode plugin but in my case bakground mode activate function is not fire in background ?

Answer (score 6):

**17/09/2019**

This works fine for me on `Ionic 4` app. Tested both on `Android` and `iOS` devices.

*app.componet.ts*

```
async initializeApp() {
    await this.platform.ready();

    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.setPlatformListener();
   }
 }


  setPlatformListener() {
    this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {// background
      console.log('In Background');
    });

    this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {// foreground
      console.log('In Foreground');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Using an angular abstraction of `ionic.Platform`

```
//The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application
// into the background, typically when the user switches to a different 
// application.
$ionicPlatform.on('pause', function () {
    // Handle event on pause
});
// The resume event fires when the native platform
//  pulls the application out from the background.
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function () {
    // Handle event on resume
});
```

Refer to [ionic v1 documentation for $ionicPlatform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
import { Platform, Config, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

...

```
constructor( private platform: Platform)
```

...

```
this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
      // Handle event on resume
    });


this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
          // Handle event on pause
        });
```

Comment: I tried ur code its working but can i call watchPosition function is call inside pause event?

Comment: @Kapilsoni you have to implement a foreground service like https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/foreground-service or background mode https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

For those using Capacitor: the [`App` plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app) can be used to subscribe to `appStateChange` events.

For Capacitor v2, import and use the plugin with the following code:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { App } = Plugins;

App.addListener('appStateChange', (state) => {
  // state.isActive contains the active state
  console.log('App state changed. Is active?', state.isActive);
});
```

For Capacitor v3+, install `@capacitor/app`, perform a Capacitor sync (`npx cap sync`), and then import and use the plugin with the following code:

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

App.addListener('appStateChange', (state) => {
  console.log('App state changed. Is active?', state.isActive);
});
```

Capacitor v4+ provides two additional events called `pause` and `resume` that can be subscribed to instead of the `appStateChange` event:

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

App.addListener('pause', () => {
  console.log('The app was paused');
});
```

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

App.addListener('resume', () => {
  console.log('The app was resumed');
});
```

According to the [Capacitor documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#addlistenerappstatechange-), the `appStateChange` event depends on the [`UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622973-willresignactivenotification) and the [`UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622953-didbecomeactivenotification) on iOS devices, whereas the `pause` event depends on the [`UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623071-didenterbackgroundnotification), and the `resume` event depends on the [`UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622944-willenterforegroundnotification) on iOS devices.

I'm unfamiliar with the specifics of how these events differ, but there certainly does seem to be a difference between them (e.g. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54253775/3513260)).

On Android, the `appStateChange`, `pause`, and `resume` events all seem to depend on the same native events: [`onResume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onResume()) and [`onStop`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onStop()).

If you need to check what the current state of the app is without waiting for any of the afore mentioned events to fire, you can use the [`getState`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#getstate) method on Capacitor v2+.

Answer (score -1):

```
initializeApp() {
  //Subscribe on pause i.e. background or lock phone
       this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
          console.log('pause')
      });
  //Subscribe on pause i.e. background or unlock phone
      this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
          console.log('resume');
     });
}
```