# How to use the events 'pause' and 'resume' in an Angular/Ionic project?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

In an Angular/Ionic project, where would I use the following attributes to appropriately handle my needs?

```
document.addEventListener('pause', actiontobeperformed, false);
document.addEventListener('resume', actiontobeperformed , false);
```

*My needs are:*

I am building an app that is protected, meaning that you can only view the content when:

you enter the correct access code
your session has not timed out
But when you go to Home, then I want somehow to record that the session is over and that the user needs to authenticate when he comes back in the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check app running in foreground or background in ionic/cordova/phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606012/how-to-check-app-running-in-foreground-or-background-in-ionic-cordova-phonegap)

Comment: @sithys: I think I need to rewrite question to: how to use these events in AngularJS? As it is not firing

Comment: I have reformulated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cordova [pause event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause) might be your answer.

And [resume](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume) when they return.

Comment: Thanks for that. Where would I put this code in an Angular project?

Comment: @JohnAndrews I have no idea, sorry. I see the question has changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.addEventListener('pause', actiontobeperformed, false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', actiontobeperformed , false);
});
```

In your js first line or in html inside script tag

Comment: Thanks for that. Where would I put this code in an Angular project?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve a functionalty like you describe would be like this:

After the User authenticated his Session with his credentials you set a value into the localStorage with `localStorage.login=1;` for example.

You now add the eventlistener for pause like `document.addEventListener('pause', actiontobeperformed, false);` and call the function `actiontobeperformed` after that.

```
function actiontobeperformed() {
    localStorage.login=0;
}
```

The only thing you still need is a function which checks the login status. Therefore you could use an if else statement

```
if (localStorage.login == 1) {
    goto menu;
} else {
    goto loginpage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ionic, you should use $ionicPlatform Service, an abstraction of ionic.Platform.   [read more](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

```
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
      // your staff here
});

$ionicPlatform.on('pause', function(){
      // your staff here
});
```

So if you want to close session when user press Home button, you should call your  AuthService.logout() method inside on Pause code block.