# Catch click anywhere/button press/input focus in angular/ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've an ionic app with auto-logout feature. When user performs any action I need to extend session timeout. I store time left in localstorage (using localStorageService).

I am able to extend time when user change screens or click buttons, but I am not sure how to do this on the rest of elements.

I simply need a way to catch any action (click on background, focus on element, button press) etc. What is the simplest way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think it can be simpler than you are trying... you can add an event listener to see when your app goes to _background_: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29609534/4227915)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to listen for a `touchend` event, and keep a timeout; something like this:

```
.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {   
    var timeoutPromise,
        $body = document.querySelector("body");

    function logout () {
        // do logout work here
    }

    function resetTimer () {
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
        timeoutPromise = $timeout(logout, 60000); // log out after 60 seconds
    }

    ionic.on("touchstart", resetTimer, $body);
    ionic.on("touchend", resetTimer, $body);
    resetTimer();
});
```

a few sources:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.EventController/
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Where should I use that code? In my controller? In config?

Comment: In your controller; I can update with more ionic-specific code.

Comment: Please do so if possible