# Stop push notification vibrate when app is open

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have an ionic(v1) app in which push notifications are sent through node-gcm and received by ngCordova push plugin. By default the phone vibrates when there is a push notification. It even vibrates when the app is open. How can I make the phone vibrate only when the app is running in background. The phone shouldn't vibrate when the user is using the app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `cordova-plugin-vibration`

installation :`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration`
you can cancel vibration like this `navigator.vibrate(0)`

more https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-vibration/

Comment: This has to work in correlation with push plugin. When the app is opened it shouldn't vibrate. When the app is closed it should vibrate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606012/how-to-check-app-running-in-foreground-or-background-in-ionic-cordova-phonegap  this help you to find current state of the app.after cheking this u can use  vibration -plugin according to the state ryt..?