# how to check app running in foreground or background in cordova specially on ios platform (onResume and onPause not working for me)

Tags: ios, cordova, onresume, hybrid, onpause

I have implement below solution for my cordova applications from the below link and it works on android but not not working on ios platform
The onPause and onResume events are not working on ios.

[how to check app running in foreground or background in ionic/cordova/phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606012/how-to-check-app-running-in-foreground-or-background-in-ionic-cordova-phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the API has been updated to pause and resume

```
 document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
 document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```

Hard to tell without your code

Check the doc here : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/cordova/events/events.html#page-toc-source