# Detect when app is in app switcher for iOS ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm wondering if there is an Ionic way to detect if the app is in iOS app switcher mode. I saw that there is a `pause` event from platform that gets fired, but it fires when the app is totally in the background which is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can't really detect the "switch" event, but you can detect when you are paused or in background (what is the same thing at the end).

With Cordova please see :
[how to check app running in foreground or background in ionic/cordova/phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606012/how-to-check-app-running-in-foreground-or-background-in-ionic-cordova-phonegap)

With Capacitor please see :
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#addlistenerpause-